# Updating a balance if bet has won

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am developing a small betting site and I have `tblAccounts` and `tblBackers`.
I wish to update a users balance column in `tblAccounts` when they have bet on the winner.

Bets are stored in `tblBackers` which has columns `amountBacked`, `backersAccountID` and the user/player they have chose to win (`playerBacked`)

The winning accountID is passed in as `@accountID` so I need it to check `tblBackers` and
update the balance of `backersPlayerID` with the amountBacked for every occurrance of `playerBacked = @accountID`

This is the procedure I created so far to achieve this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdatePayout]
@accountID uniqueidentifier

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF (SELECT playerBacked from tblBackers)=@accountID
BEGIN
UPDATE tblAccounts
SET balance = balance + (SELECT amountBacked FROM tblBackers WHERE 
playerBacked = @accountID)
WHERE AccountID=(SELECT backersAccountID from tblBackers)
END

END
```

Here is the error encountered

> Subquery returned more than 1 value.
>   This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <= , >, >=
>   or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: The error is because `WHERE AccountID=(SELECT backersAccountID from tblBackers)` returns more than one record as there is no **WHERE** condition in the `SubQuery`

Comment: There are several logical errors in this code in addition to the error message. For example, the IF condition is extremely brittle. It will get the value from the last row returned from tblBackers. And with no order by you don't even know which row that might be. That should probably be changed to an EXISTS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to only return one result from the inner query, A sum aggregate would add all of the instances of amount backed together for the account id and then return that value

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdatePayout]
@accountID uniqueidentifier

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;


IF (SELECT playerBacked from tblBackers)=@accountID
BEGIN
UPDATE tblAccounts
SET balance = balance + (SELECT SUM(amountBacked) FROM tblBackers WHERE 
playerBacked = @accountID)
WHERE AccountID=(SELECT backersAccountID from tblBackers)
END

END
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still getting same error. To clarify what I'm wanting...
A bet would be inserted as one row in tblBackers like this..
backersAccountID, playerBacked, amountBacked

The winning player is @accountID which needs checking for a match against playerBacked. If it matches then the amountBacked needs adding to balance in tblAccounts where tblAccounts.accountID= backersAccountID

The next row in tblBackers then needs paying out as it will be from a different backersAccountID

And so on until the end of that table is reached.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood it right 
`tblBackers` has the list of user who bets on another player and the amount he is betting. 
`tblAccounts` has the list of user and his balance.

So when an AccountID, for example, **12345** bets on **99999** he has to be credited the **25 amount** he had bet

```
CREATE TABLE #tblBackers (
amountBacked MONEY, 
backersAccountID INT,
playerBacked INT)

CREATE TABLE #tblAccounts (
Balance MONEY, 
AccountID INT)


INSERT INTO #tblBackers VALUES (25,12345,99999)
INSERT INTO #tblBackers VALUES (25,98765,88888)
INSERT INTO #tblBackers VALUES (25,76543,77777)

INSERT INTO #tblAccounts VALUES (50,12345)

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdatePayout]
@AccountID INT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 from #tblBackers WHERE backersAccountID = @AccountID)
BEGIN
    UPDATE #tblAccounts
    SET balance = balance + (SELECT SUM(amountBacked) FROM #tblBackers WHERE 
    backersAccountID = @AccountID)
    WHERE AccountID IN (SELECT backersAccountID from #tblBackers WHERE backersAccountID = @AccountID)
END
END


EXEC [UpdatePayout] 12345


SELECT * FROM #tblAccounts
```

> Updated SQL Query

```
CREATE TABLE #tblBackers (
amountBacked MONEY, 
backersAccountID INT,
playerBacked INT)
GO

CREATE TABLE #tblAccounts (
Balance MONEY, 
AccountID INT)
GO

INSERT INTO #tblBackers VALUES (25,12345,99999)
INSERT INTO #tblBackers VALUES (25,12345,66666)
INSERT INTO #tblBackers VALUES (25,98765,88888)
INSERT INTO #tblBackers VALUES (25,76543,77777)
GO

INSERT INTO #tblAccounts VALUES (50,12345)

GO

SELECT * FROM #tblAccounts
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdatePayout]
@AccountID INT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 from #tblBackers WHERE playerBacked = @AccountID)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE #tblAccounts
        SET balance = Balance + (SELECT SUM(amountBacked)*2 FROM #tblBackers WHERE 
        playerBacked = @AccountID) 
        WHERE AccountID IN (SELECT backersAccountID from #tblBackers WHERE playerBacked = @AccountID)
    END
END

GO

EXEC [UpdatePayout] 99999

GO

SELECT * FROM #tblAccounts
```

> Updated SP to handle multiple records

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdatePayout]
@AccountID INT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
RowID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
AmountBacked MONEY,
BackersAccountID INT,
PlayerBacked INT
)

INSERT INTO @Test 
SELECT AmountBacked, BackersAccountID, PlayerBacked FROM #tblBackers WHERE PlayerBacked = @AccountID

DECLARE @AmountBacked MONEY
DECLARE @BackersAccountID INT

    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from @Test WHERE PlayerBacked = @AccountID)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @AmountBacked = AmountBacked, @BackersAccountID = BackersAccountID FROM @Test WHERE PlayerBacked = @AccountID

        UPDATE #tblAccounts
        SET balance = Balance + (SELECT SUM(@AmountBacked)*2) 
        WHERE AccountID IN (@BackersAccountID)

        DELETE FROM @Test WHERE BackersAccountID = @BackersAccountID

        SELECT @BackersAccountID = NULL
        SET @AmountBacked = NULL
    END
END

GO

EXEC [UpdatePayout] 99999

GO
```

Comment: Ooooh.. This is really helpful thank you. It's stopped the error but I've changed a bit in the WHERE statements as the incoming accountID needs checking against playerBacked not backersAccountID.

Using this code, it now adds the total amount in column amountBacked to each backersAccountID  I know its hard to understand what I'm wanting to do here, very sorry for that.. but it's so close now. I just need the code below to add only the value of amountBacked in 1st maching row to the backersAccountID then amountBacked in 2nd matching row to the backersAccountID and so on to the end of table.

Comment: IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 from tblBackers WHERE backersAccountID = @AccountID)
    BEGIN
    UPDATE tblAccounts
    SET balance = balance + (SELECT SUM(amountBacked) FROM 
    tblBackers WHERE
    playerBacked = @AccountID)
    WHERE AccountID IN (SELECT backersAccountID from tblBackers 
    WHERE playerBacked = @AccountID)
    END

Comment: Were you able to get it work ?, or are you still facing issues ?

Comment: No, I'm still stuck :-( It needs to check each row in tblBackers and where ever it finds playerBacked=@accountID it needs to set the balance in the corresponding backersAccountID to balance=balance+amountBacked. Actually that shoud be balance+amountBacked*2 as they win double their original amountBacked. Sorry I know I'm a pain but your answer is the closest I've got.

Comment: Thanks again for the update.. I'm simply taking the main code and putting it straight in to the stored procedure.. There's 2 bets in tblbackers where I'm testing it and they are a £1 stake from 1 member and a £2 from another member. Its paying both members £3 each instead of £2 winnings to 1st member and £4 winnings to the other. I think you're taking the sum of amountBacked instead of just giving double the amount backed by each user. I'm so sorry, I don't know how to correct it, I just know it's very close. Thanks in advance for anything else you can do.

Comment: Just to clarify, were to able to fix it? 
What do you mean by ` I'm simply taking the main code and putting it straight into the stored procedure` is this **SP** `UpdatePayout` called within another **SP**?
Also if multiple players can bet on the same User then you may need to pass the _AccountID_ from **tblAccounts**  too